# -[NSString dataUsingEncoding:] gives garbage at end of string in iOS 9, not iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, malloc, byte, ios9

The following code runs fine on iOS 8 but when run on iOS 9.0.2 I get some odd results:

```
NSString * input = @"Hi there";
NSData * data = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(data.length);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], data.length);

NSString * result = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char*)byteData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
```

iOS 8.4 (iPhone 6 Plus) `byteData` is `Hi there`

iOS 9.0.2 (iPhone 6S) `byteData` is `Hi there\xb6<M\x13`

On iOS 9 I end up with a load of garbage at the end of the string.

This feels like a 32 bit vs 64 bit issue as it looks like on iOS 9 the byteData length is twice as long?

Apple have their table of 32 to 64 bit changes here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html

`data.length` is an `unsigned long long`. Could this be returning different lengths when `malloc` is called? The code above returns `8` for `data.length` when run on each version of iOS.

This just feels quite odd and I've run out of angles to attack it from. Hopefully someone out there might be able to shed some light on this one.

Thanks!

**Update**

I can fix it using

```
NSString * result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:byteData length:data.length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

but I'd still like to know why I get a different result on the two iOS versions with

```
NSString * result = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char*)byteData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Can you share the entire code, including the code that prints the result ? Have you checked that data is never nil ?

Comment: The 32-/64-bit divide is irrelevant here: there's no difference between iOS 8 and 9, and the value is dependent on _device_ anyways. Both the 6+ and the 6S are 64-bit devices.

Comment: Show how you see the value of `byteData`. Your code is fine in all cases. I think it's a simple matter of how you view the value. It seems you are trying to view the data as a C string and in case the memory happened to be followed by a null character and under iOS 9 it wasn't. But this is a flaw in how you are viewing the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A “C string” ends with a NUL byte. Since you created `data` using `dataUsingEncoding:`, `data` does not contain a C string.

Since `stringWithCString:encoding:` is reading outside of valid memory (looking for the NUL terminator), the behavior is undefined and thus allowed to changed at any time.

Use `cStringUsingEncoding:` to create `data` and you'll get the NUL terminator you need.

Comment: Right, I see. So the behaviour for this has changed between the two versions of iOS and that's why I'm seeing different results. I can see now what I'm doing wrong with viewing the result. Thanks for the clarification.